# How do I see Gradle Warnings on Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently updated to Android Studio 0.5.9. Before updating it, the Event Log would just say "Gradle completed with 0 errors or warnings" after compiling the project, but now it says "Gradle build finished with 2 warnings(s) in x sec". How can I find what is causing these warnings?

EDIT: If anyone is having these warnings after 0.5.9 update, I reinstalled Android Studio and the Gradle warnings are gone.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Look at the Messages view (default key shortcut: Alt+0)

Answer (score 9):

On a Mac, it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

(The accepted answer is for windows)

Answer (score 0):

Try go to indicate directory(....gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts) and rename file cache.properties.lock to cache.properties